aggregating a pyspark column gives error: unsupported operand type pyspark +: int and str
I have a simple dataframe with decimal type values.
col1 col2
2     3
3     3
I wish to sum using:
df = df.agg(sum("col1"))
This does not work if the code is outside of a class in pyspark. I get an error: unsupported operand type pyspark +: int and str
I tried casting to integer, double, decimal etc.
But all of this works if it is inside a class.
Since it is a test data, they are all integers/whatever value I cast them to.

Is it possible that there are None, null or NaN values in col1? Could you also share the relevant code so that it is a bit more clear what you have tried?
